# XPATH: How to use a variable in call-template

Tags: xslt, xpath

I am writing an XSLT to transform an XML: I am not experienced in Xpath, and my XML is too big to post.

But here is my problem:

This code: works fine:

```
<cac:testmathieu>           
  <xsl:variable name="lineAmount2" select="body:LineAmount * -1" />             
  <xsl:value-of select="../body:TaxTrans[body:TaxBaseAmount=$lineAmount2]/body:TaxAmount"/>
</cac:testmathieu>
```

Then, why is the code below not working, when it's used right below the above code:

```
 <xsl:call-template name ="TaxTotalLine">
   <xsl:with-param name="TaxAmount" select="../body:TaxTrans[body:TaxBaseAmount=body:LineAmount*-1]/body:TaxAmount"></xsl:with-param>
 </xsl:call-template>
```

The second piece of code is just a merge of of the code in the first example, or am I mistaken?

Comment: The second code is calling a template `TaxTotalLine` and passing a parameter. What it does? Show me the template and I'd tell you.

Comment: In variable you have body:LineAmount * -1 and in parameter body:LineAmount*-1, you need to add spaces as in variable, please my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want

```
 <xsl:call-template name ="TaxTotalLine">
   <xsl:with-param name="TaxAmount" select="../body:TaxTrans[body:TaxBaseAmount = current()/body:LineAmount*-1]/body:TaxAmount"></xsl:with-param>
 </xsl:call-template>
```

to compare the LineAmount of the currently processed node (e.g. any outer template or for-each) to the TaxBaseAmout of the TaxTrans element you have applied the predicate in square brackets to.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the response.

It was acutally a combination of the "current()" and the brackets.

Much appreciated !

Kind regards

Mathieu